# What's the best pattern to add simple public method in jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, plugins

I've read several articles about best jquery plugin patterns, including official docs -

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/

https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/patterns/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

but nevetheless cannot decide what is the best to suite my needs, maybe someone will advice.

I need to make a public method from function that is inner now.

Currently I'm using basic plugin structure:

```
(function ($) {

   $.fn.plugin = function (options) {
     var defaults = {
       someoption: true
     };

     options = $.extend(defaults, options);

     return this.each(function () {
       // all logic goes here...
       if (options.someoption) {
         mainMethod();
       }

       function mainMethod () {
         // main method bla bla..
         // also calls in certain circumstances this func:
         somePublicMethod();
       }

       function somePublicMethod () {
         // AND this method should be accessible like:
         // $('elem').plugin('somePublicMethod');
       }
     });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

this `somePublicMethod()` func should be accessible like `$('elem').plugin('somePublicMethod');`

Do you have ideas?

Comment: The intention for which you need plugin is what you need to find out first.obviously there are plenty of plugins for various operations

Comment: i'm talking about patterns :)

Comment: `http://jqueryboilerplate.com/` this plugin would be the best as for beginners, where as ` http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring` can be used for reference.

Comment: @dreamweiver it's nice and i've looked at this but it's not about adding methods along with options

Answer (score 6):

Im using this pattern for my plugins. It allows me to have private and public methods and also disable calling methods if the plugin is not initialised

```js
;(function($, window, undefined) {
    'use strict';        

    /**
     * My Plugin
     * v1.0
     */ 
    $.MyPlugin = function(options, element) {
        // this element
        this.$el = $(element);
        this._init(options); 
    };

    $.MyPlugin.defaults = {
        default1: 1,
        default2: 2
    };

    $.MyPlugin.prototype = {
        /**
        * Private methods
        */
        _init: function(options) {
            // options
            this.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.MyPlugin.defaults, options);
        }, 

        _privateMethod: function() {

        },                                                               

        /**
        * Public methods
        */
        publicMethod: function() {

        }
    }; 

    var logError = function(message) {
        if(window.console) {
            window.console.error(message);
        }                                   
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) { 
        this.each(function() {
            var self = $.data(this, 'myPlugin');

            if(typeof options === 'string') {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

                if(!self) {
                    logError('cannot call methods on myPlugin prior to initialization; ' +
                    'attempted to call method ' + options);
                    return;               
                }

                if(!$.isFunction(self[options]) || options.charAt(0) === '_') {
                    logError('no such method ' + options + ' for myPlugin self');
                    return;                                                     
                }

                self[options].apply(self, args);

            } else {     
                if(self) {      
                    self._init();  
                } else {             
                    self = $.data(this, 'myPlugin', new $.MyPlugin(options, this));
                }
            } 
        });

        return this;
    }; 
})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: and you are also able to use "publicMethod" inside "_privateMethod"?

Comment: you can use all methods inside your plugin. the private methods cant be used by plugin users. the methods are actualy not private. you cant make private method in javascript its just best practice thing. plugin users cant call `$('#test').myPlugin('_privateMethod')`

Comment: yeah, i know about this.. that's why i thought to create something like ``methods = {}`` object where will be stored only public accessible methods

Comment: I had to move `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);` above the this.each.  I think this is because underscore or something overwrote `each` and caused `arguments` to be reset.